Observer and computed not working with reaction
       import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
         
         part 'auth_store.g.dart';
         class AuthStore = AuthStoreBase with _$AuthStore;
         
         abstract class AuthStoreBase with Store {
           AuthStoreBase() {
             _setupValidations();
           }
         
         
         
           late List<ReactionDisposer> _disposers;
         
         
           void _setupValidations() {
             _disposers = [
               reaction((_) => _selectedCountryIndex, setSelectedCountryIndex,
                   fireImmediately: true),
             ];
           }
         
           @observable
           int _selectedCountryIndex = 0;
         
           @computed
           int get selectedCountryIndexInt => _selectedCountryIndex;
         
           @action
           void setSelectedCountryIndex(int val) {
             _selectedCountryIndex = val;
           }
         
           @computed
           String get selectedCountryCode => "+$_selectedCountryIndex";
         
           // ------------------ Disposer ------------------
           void dispose() {
             for (var e in _disposers) {
               e();
             }
           }
         }

When using computed flags in the UI, they do not update automatically. I either need to use setState, or the changes become visible only after scrolling or when the widget's lifecycle is updated.
here is UI code
       Observer(
                          builder: (_) {
                          final selectedCountryCode =
                          injector<AuthStore>().selectedCountryCode;
                          int selectedCountryIndexInt =
                          injector<AuthStore>().selectedCountryIndexInt;
                            return RippleEffect(
                              onTap: () {
                                injector<AuthStore>()
                                    .setSelectedCountryIndex(selectedCountryIndexInt + 1);
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "$selectedCountryCode \\ $selectedCountryIndexInt",
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),

Here is package details:
build_runner: 2.4.10
mobx_codegen: 2.7.0
mobx: 2.5.0
flutter_mobx: 2.3.0

Update computed flag on reaction change and able to view in ongo process
